# My calculation is producing half the results needed. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, one is called CarTypes and the other is called Hourly Rates.

CarType has following attributes:

```
Id,
CarTypes,
Rates
HourlyID related to HourlyRates based on HourlyId-ID relationship.
Id is an AutoNumber
CarTypes are Sedan, 
Sports Utility, 
Stretch Limo 6 Passengers, 
Stretch Limo 8 passengers
Stretch Limo 10 Passengers
Stretch Limo 12 Passengers
```

Each car type has its own rates.

Then table HourlyRates has following attributes:
ID autoNumber,
Hourly (mininum hour is 3) maximum is 13 and over

Our task is to multiply the assigned fare for each cartype by the hours user selected, determine the discount amount for 10%, determine the tax amount for (7% tax), determine the tip or gratuity amount for (20%).
Finally, So, substract discount from the fare, add tax amount, add tip amount to generate total amount.

My calculation so far is only displaying all the values (fare, discount, tip, total) for only two car types, Sedan and Sports Utility vehicles.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.carTypes, h.hourly, h.hourly * IIf([CarTypes] = 'Sedan', 55, 
           IIf([CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 6 Passenger)', 75,
           IIf([CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 8 Passenger)', 90,
           IIf([CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 10  Passenger)', 95,
           IIf([CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 12  Passenger)', 110,
            IIf([CarTypes] = 'SportUtilityVehicle)', 110)))))) AS Fare, Fare*10/100 AS Discount, Fare-Discount AS NewFare, NewFare* 7/100 AS Tax, NewFare* 20/100 AS Tip, NewFare+Tax+TIP AS Total
FROM HourlyRates AS h INNER JOIN carType AS c ON h.ID= c.hourlyID;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got extra `)` in the name of each `CarType` other than Sedan, so they are never captured in the nested `IIF()` criteria.

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.carTypes, h.hourly, h.hourly * IIf([CarTypes] = 'Sedan', 55, 
           IIf([CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 6 Passenger', 75,
           IIf([CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 8 Passenger', 90,
           IIf([CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 10  Passenger', 95,
           IIf([CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 12  Passenger', 110,
            IIf([CarTypes] = 'SportUtilityVehicle', 110)))))) AS Fare, Fare*10/100 AS Discount, Fare-Discount AS NewFare, NewFare* 7/100 AS Tax, NewFare* 20/100 AS Tip, NewFare+Tax+TIP AS Total
FROM HourlyRates AS h INNER JOIN carType AS c ON h.ID= c.hourlyID;
```

The `SWITCH()` function is a little easier to read in my opinion:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.carTypes, h.hourly, h.hourly * 
            SWITCH([CarTypes] = 'Sedan', 55
                  ,[CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 6 Passenger', 75
                  ,[CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 8 Passenger', 90
                  ,[CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 10  Passenger', 95
                  ,[CarTypes] = 'Stretch Limo : 12  Passenger', 110
                  ,[CarTypes] = 'SportUtilityVehicle', 110
                  )  AS Fare
            , Fare*10/100 AS Discount
            , Fare-Discount AS NewFare
            , NewFare* 7/100 AS Tax
            , NewFare* 20/100 AS Tip
            , NewFare+Tax+TIP AS Total
FROM HourlyRates AS h INNER JOIN carType AS c ON h.ID= c.hourlyID;
```

Comment: thank you!

That's exactly the problem.

I will try the SWITCH () function.

Again, thanks